# How to get execution time and add it to my class?

Tags: python

I had exercise to code this simple to do list.

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, task_name):
        self.task_name = [task_name, "[ ]"]

    def finish(self):
        self.task_name[1] = "[x]"


class ToDoList:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list = []

    def add_task(self, object):
        self.task = object.task_name
        self.list.append(self.task)

    def print_list(self):
        print(self.name)
        print("##########")
        for i in self.list:
            print(i[1], i[0])
```

The code needed to work with this implementation:

```
mylist = ToDoList('My sample ToDoList')
for i in range(1, 11):
    task = Task(f'Simple task #{i}')
    if i % 2:
        task.finish()
    mylist.add_task(task)
mylist.print_list()
```

and I needed to get results like this. The x is a mark that task is done.

```
My sample ToDoList
##########
[x] Simple task #1
[ ] Simple task #2
[x] Simple task #3
[ ] Simple task #4
[x] Simple task #5
[ ] Simple task #6
[x] Simple task #7
[ ] Simple task #8
[x] Simple task #9
[ ] Simple task #10
```

This is fine. The next part of the exercise is to add execution time starting from adding it to list and ending when it's marked as finished. The output given should be like this:

```
My sample ToDoList with time
###
[x] Simple timed task #1 [1 s]
[ ] Simple timed task #2 [--- s]
[x] Simple timed task #3 [2 s]
[ ] Simple timed task #4 [--- s]
[x] Simple timed task #5 [3 s]
[ ] Simple timed task #6 [--- s]
[x] Simple timed task #7 [4 s]
[ ] Simple timed task #8 [--- s]
[x] Simple timed task #9 [5 s]
[ ] Simple timed task #10 [--- s]
```

And should work with this verification code:

```
mylist = ToDoList('My sample ToDoList with time')
tasks = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    task = Task(f'Simple timed task #{i}')
    tasks.append(task)
time.sleep(2)
for task in tasks:
    mylist.add_task(task)
for idx, task in enumerate(tasks):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        task.finish()
mylist.print_list()
```

I was able to get this halfway done because I get this output:

```
My sample ToDoList with time
##########
[x] Simple timed task #1 [--- s]
[ ] Simple timed task #2 
[x] Simple timed task #3 [--- s]
[ ] Simple timed task #4 
[x] Simple timed task #5 [--- s]
[ ] Simple timed task #6 
[x] Simple timed task #7 [--- s]
[ ] Simple timed task #8 
[x] Simple timed task #9 [--- s]
[ ] Simple timed task #10
```

but I'm stuck on how to do time in this. My full code right now:

```
import time
class Task:
    def __init__(self, task_name):
        self.task_name = [task_name, "[ ]", ""]

    def finish(self):
        self.task_name[1] = "[x]"
        self.task_name[2] = "[--- s]"


class ToDoList:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list = []

    def add_task(self, object):
        self.task = object.task_name
        self.list.append(self.task)

    def print_list(self):
        print(self.name)
        print("##########")
        for i in self.list:
            print(i[1], i[0], i[2])

mylist = ToDoList('My sample ToDoList with time')
tasks = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    task = Task(f'Simple timed task #{i}')
    tasks.append(task)
time.sleep(2)
for task in tasks:
    mylist.add_task(task)
for idx, task in enumerate(tasks):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        task.finish()
mylist.print_list()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add a `start_time` attribute to Task (you need to import time):

```
import time

# in Task.__init__
    self.start_time = time.time()

# in Task.finish
    self.end_time = time.time()
    self.task_name[2] = '[' + str(self.end_time - self.start_time) + ' s]'
    # you may want to round the number before converting to string
```

edit:

you are currently only storing the list of the task in the ToDoList, not the Task itself. you probably want to change this:

```
import time
class Task:
    def __init__(self, task_name):
        self.task_name = [task_name, "[ ]", "[0 s]"]
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.finished = False
    def finish(self):
        self.task_name[1] = "[x]"
        self.task_name[2] = "[--- s]"
        self.finished = True
    def update(self):
        if not self.finished:
            self.task_name[2] = '[' + str(round(time.time() - self.start_time)) + ' s]'


class ToDoList:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list = []
    def add_task(self, task):
        self.list.append(task)
    def print_list(self):
        print(self.name)
        print("##########")
        for i in self.list:
            i.update()
            print(i.task_name[1], i.task_name[0], i.task_name[2])

mylist = ToDoList('My sample ToDoList with time')
tasks = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    task = Task(f'Simple timed task #{i}')
    tasks.append(task)

time.sleep(2)
for task in tasks:
    mylist.add_task(task)

for idx, task in enumerate(tasks):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        task.finish()

mylist.print_list()
```

NOTE:
all tasks will show 9 secs because the are created simultaniously.

Comment: I changed your line to this: self.task_name[2] = '[' + str(round(self.end_time - self.start_time)) + ' s]', but I get time starting from 3s and not from 1s. Do you maybe know why ?

Comment: Also It shouldn't add time to finished task. Finished task should have [--- s].

Comment: the tasks are starting at 3 secs because of `time.sleep(2)` after creating the tasks. for the [--- s] i misunderstood the question and update the answer.

Comment: But still the output is wrong. For example the first two line should be [x] Simple timed task #1 [1 s]
[ ] Simple timed task #2 [--- s], but right now It's [x] Simple timed task #1 [3 s]
[ ] Simple timed task #2 .